# se pierde la posición de elemento HTML con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hago una validación para cada input dinámico, bajo cada input pinto un mensaje de error si no pasó la validación.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi elemento HTML dinamico `(div)` no pierda el id cuando paso del input 2 al input 9 de mi tabla HTML?

Con el siguiente código, el id del div 9 es 3 y debería ser 9, es por ello que en la imagen se ve que en el input 3 esta el mensaje de error pero ese no lo había validado aun.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll("input");
var m = 0;
for (var b in a) {

var c = a[b];
if (typeof c == "object") {

    c.onfocusout = function() {

        console.log(this.id);
        console.log(this.value);
        var hola = $(this).parent().parent();
        var celdas = hola.children();

        var cliente = $(celdas[1]).text();
        var factura = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'validaNotacredito',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                cliente: cliente,
                factura: factura
            },

            error: function() {
                $("#divError").html("Error al validar nota de crédito");
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log($("#divError-" + m).html(response));
            }

        });

        m = m + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Tambien tengo otro problema.

Cada input genera su id, en este caso, yo le he concatenado el número de fila de mi tabla html para diferenciarlo de los demás input, pero el código anterior genera id infinitos, es decir que si mi tabla tiene 10 filas y coloco el foco en el input 1, me genera el id 11 y así sucesivamente las veces que le coloque el foco a ese input o a otro y esto no debería ser así ya que solo hay 10 filas.

Comment: @Alfonso Carrasco este es mi codigo

Comment: No se entiende mucho... y como debería quedar?

Comment: @Hector el mensaje de error(validación) que esta en el input 3 debería estar en el input 9, con el código fuente de arriba lo que hace es que las validaciones(código AJAX) las hace de arriba abajo y no pueden ser de otra forma, por ejemplo si yo quisiera validar el input 9 tendría que llenar los input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haber checa el código y dime si te sirve de algo. Ando ahora un poco ocupadon.. Pero me doy tiempo... Saludos..

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
for(var b in a){
 var c = a[b];
 if(typeof c == "object"){
   c.onblur = function (){
     //Datos del input
     var valorFactura = this.value;
     var nombreFactura = this.name;
    //accesamos al TD y TR 
     var td = this.offsetParent;
     var tr = td.parentElement;
    //Accesamos a las Columnas de tu TR
     var c_fila = tr.children[0].textContent;
     var c_cliente = tr.children[1].textContent;
     var c_nombre = tr.children[2].textContent;
     var c_tc = tr.children[3].textContent;
     var c_tdc = tr.children[4].textContent;
     var c_a = tr.children[5].textContent;
     var c_m = tr.children[6].textContent;
     var c_cn = tr.children[6].textContent;
    //consola de las columnas...
     console.log(valorFactura,nombreFactura,c_fila,c_cliente,c_nombre, c_tc, c_tdc, c_a, c_m, c_cn);
   }
 }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
  <tr><td>Fila</td><td>Cliente</td><td>Nombre</td><td>TC</td><td>T a C</td><td>A %</td><td>M en $</td><td>Con</td><td>Fac</td></tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>BB</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura1" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>BB2</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura2" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>BB3</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura3" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>BB4</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura4" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>BB5</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura5" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>BB</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura1" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>BB2</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura2" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>BB3</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura3" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>BB4</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura4" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>BB5</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura5" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>BB</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura6" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>BB2</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura7" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>BB3</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura8" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>BB4</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura9" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>BB5</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura10" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>BB</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura11" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>BB2</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura12" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>BB3</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura13" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>BB4</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura14" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>BB5</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura15" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>BB</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura16" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>BB2</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura17" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>BB3</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura18" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>BB4</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura18" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>BB5</td><td>CC</td><td>DD</td><td>EE</td><td>FF</td><td>GG</td><td>HH</td><td><input type="text" name="factura20" /></td></tr>

<tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: si funciona perfecto solo una pequeñita cuestión que no he podido controlar y es que si mi tabla html tiene 10 filas, los id de los input van del 1-10 ya que cada fila es el identificador de cada input y cuando ya ingrese información en los input y me regreso por ejemplo al input 6 para cambiar la información en teoria deberia ser el id 6 pero el código genera un id nuevo que en este caso seria el 11

Comment: Ok, mira voy a editar mi ejemplo y voy agregarle 20 registros de ahí yo creo que ya podrás ver que sucede con el tuyo... De hecho no debe cambiar en nada...

Comment: si  te lo agradezco mucho =)

Comment: Listo ya puedes revisarlo

Comment: creo que ya esta bro, es que tenia el div donde mostraba el mensaje de error si no pasaba la validación y tenia un contador que se incrementaba en uno $("#divError-" + m).html(response), por eso se hacia infinito, cambiando la concatenación a la variable "c_fila" del codigo que compartiste ya me muestra el mensaje de error en el input adecuado, gracias... saludos

Comment: Saludos y éxito con tu código